# Feasibility of a pill with the opposite effect of birth control?

Tags: internal-consistency, biochemistry

Could a pill be made that instead of preventing pregnancy induces a successful pregnancy after sexual intercourse? This article seems to answer my question and is what inspired it, but I'm not 100% sure.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.theguardian.com/science/2017/sep/20/dna-editing-in-human-embryos-reveals-role-of-fertility-master-gene

Comment: Certainly.  One form of fertility treatment is to supply hormones, though as of about 20 years ago, it was injections rather than a pill, at least in my friends' case.  (The result graduated from high school last year.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are already hormonal treatments that increase ovules production in women: instead of 1 ovule per cycle, they induce the production of up to 20 ovules in a single cycle. Since likelyhood of pregnancy is proportional to the amount of available eggs, they do the trick.

It is important to note that a pregnancy with more than 1 embryo is something human body has not been selected for. The more the embryo, the higher the risks for both mother and embryo.

Comment: Men also happen to [be](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/male-infertility/basics/causes/con-20033113) [infertile](http://americanpregnancy.org/infertility/male-infertility/)...

Comment: @Olga, yes, but when it's 1 egg vs millions of sperms (providing they are present), the egg is the limiting factor.

Comment: background reading on one such drug.  http://www.advancedfertility.com/clomid-treatment.htm

Comment: @L.Dutch, in 30% of all infertility cases a man is the problem. Increased number of eggs will not solve it. A man should be treated.

Comment: @Olga, the OP doesn't ask how to cure infertility.

Comment: @L.Dutch, the OP asks to 'induce' a successful pregnancy after a sexual intercourse...

Answer (score 1):

No.

There are so many many factors required for pregnancy. Each one can stop it but everything has to be right for it to happen.

Imagine it as a chain. To stop it you just cut any link. To join the chain any link could be the problem.

No pill can fix everything that might stop it.

Comment: Well, maybe nanobot pills that were programmed to address any problems, or otherwise simply create the correct conditions despite the problems.

Comment: No nanobot pill would do it. It would have to fix everything from physical faults to editing DNA on the fly. The effort wouldn't make a pill worth it. Unless the nano bots had AI how would they know what to fix?

Better to use IVF and an artificial womb to completely bypass the issues

Answer (score 0):

If the "pill" contained an already fertilized egg (zygote), then all it would have to do is get the egg to the right spot (nano-bots, or it's not a pill that's swallowed) and maybe have a few hormones to set the environment.

Intercourse isn't even required. As to who the egg's parents are...?